# Will this approach still get these pages indexed by search engines?

Tags: php, seo

I have php modules for two different type of users. In order to prevent someone to access a module directly by guessing: domain.com/modules/user_form.php i am doing the following:

In the module page i am using:

```
if(!$included){ die("Error"); }
```

Then in the page where i am including the module:

```
$included=1;include("module.php");
```

What this does is that it makes sure that the user can't directly access this and can only see it if its being called in  a page.

My question is i am storing these like: domain.com/module.php

So will search engines be able to pick the module files up in search or because they are only being called in member pages and that they have this include code i am using will prevent them from being indexed.

---

ok let me clarify i bit. these modules are features that should only be allowed if they are called using `include("");` so i am saying if i do the `$included=1;include("");` then search won't pick it up, right? since it requires to be included in a page rather than it being a stand alone page.

Comment: not clear how you code works, or the resulting output, so question cant be answered

Answer (score 0):

I'm not following your question 100%, but If you are outputting HTML, then yes, search engines can pick it up.

Comment: ok let me clarify i bit.  these modules are features that should only be allowed if they are called using include("");  so i am saying if i do the $included=1;include(""); then search won't pick it up, right? since it requires to be included in a page rather than it being a stand alone page.

Comment: correct. SE's cant see the PHP, they only see what PHP outputs.

Answer (score 0):

If the modules are files that don't have their own url listed on your web site, or are not manually added to a robots.txt file or manually submitted to a search engine, they will not appear.

This is not however they best way to use an included file that you don't want people to have direct access to (another question altogether)

Comment: If the modules are outputting HTML they CAN get picked up by SE's. Say the module is a "Upcoming Events" module that outputs times and dates of upcoming events, this would include the the HTML on your current page. No need to add anything to a robots.txt file or submit anything to the SE's